# Crystal Reports: Keeping the master list on the report with a date range parameter

Tags: sql-server, crystal-reports

I have a single query that pulls a list of user training, the people who have completed training, and which training was completed. I am trying to use this query in my Crystal report, but I need to still show the master list of training with the date range parameter. I think I can make the report to show the master list with two commands in the report but is this possible to achieve with just one command in the report?

The query uses two tables. The **table A** has the list of the training, and the **table B** has the user information, such as user name, the training name, and the completion date. I have joined the **table B** into the **table A** to get the list of the training and see who has done the training.

```
select 
from table A a
left join table B b on b.officerID = a.OfficerID
```

Adding a date range to the query will alter the list of training shown as result.

The report needs to show the user name, the whole list of training (regardless of the date range parameter), and the dates.

```
User: XYZ
Training      Date
--------------------
ABC           7/1/20
DEF           
GHI           7/4/20
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm understading you are dealing with a schema somewhat like this:

Training <- UserTraining -> User

And you want to write one single query and show, for each user, all the trainings, regardless if he completed it.

If I got it right (or close), you could do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Training
LEFT OUTER JOIN UserTraining ON Training.Id = UserTraining.TrainingFK
LEFT OUTER JOIN User ON USER.Id = UserTraning.UserFK
```

Then, in the Crystal Reports designer, you would group by user, show user in group header, and show training and date in details. You can suppress the date field with a formula when the date does not belong to the date range.

The problem with this approach is that if your tables grows too much, you will get perfomance troubles.

A possible improvement would be to change the query:

```
SELECT * FROM Training
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT TrainingFK, Date FROM UserTraining WHERE Date BETWEEN @date_start and @date_end
) as X ON Training.Id = X.TrainingFK
LEFT OUTER JOIN User ON USER.Id = UserTraning.UserFK
```

I kept both queries in this purposed solution because I believe this way is easier to follow up, since the first query is more friendly.

Comment: Thanks. I updated my question to provide better info. I'm going to try what you suggested, though.

Comment: Your example queries do not include the rate range. I'm not sure if these queries will work the same with the date range?